# Inconsistent regex behaviour in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression that I have verified works correctly, proof is here: https://regex101.com/r/ffSVuD/6

Unfortunately when I use the same regex within some Python code I do not get the same behaviour. The regex does get a match, but it does not find the same match groups.

Here is some demo code:

```
import re
ddl_string = """
CREATE TABLE default.test_parse_partitioned_table__using_parquet_1_082921496561 (DATA4 BIGINT, DATA5 BIGINT, DATA2 BIGINT, DATA3 BIGINT)
USING parquet
OPTIONS (
  serialization.format \\'1\\'
)
PARTITIONED BY (DATA2, DATA3)
"""
regex = r'CREATE +?(TEMPORARY +)?TABLE *(?P<db>.*?\.)?(?P<table>.*?)\((?P<col>.*?)\).*?USING +([^\s]+)( +OPTIONS *\([^)]+\))?( *PARTITIONED BY \((?P<pcol>.*?)\))?'
match = re.search(regex, ddl_string, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
if match.group("pcol"):
    print match.group("pcol").strip()
else:
    print 'did not find any pcols in {matches}'.format(matches=match.groups())
```

which returns:

> did not find any pcols in (None, 'default.', 'test_parse_partitioned_table__using_parquet_1_082921496561 ', 'DATA4 BIGINT, DATA5 BIGINT, DATA2 BIGINT, DATA3 BIGINT', 'parquet', None, None, None)

My intention is to populate **DATA2, DATA3** into `match.group("pcol")` but as you will observe that is not happening. In my aforementioned regex verification at https://regex101.com/r/ffSVuD/6 it *does* find a match:

[image: regex match group pcol]

I have fiddled around quite a lot trying to get a regex that will return what I need but no success hence this post. Can anyone help?

Comment: 1) In your python code you've enabled the `re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL` flags. 2) There's a small difference in the regex pattern: `CREATE +` vs `CREATE +?`. 3) The text you're using the regex on isn't the same.

Comment: Your regex does not match when PARTITIONED BY (and OPTIONS) is on a new line

Comment: thank you both, you are both correct. I had ddl_string over multiple lines. Fixed now, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I have the impression in case there're multiple matches with grouped names it is hard to get these retrieved by the name.

[python code - to run](http://tpcg.io/_X30VID)

```
import re
import inspect

ddl_string = """
CREATE TABLE default.test_parse_partitioned_table__using_parquet_1_082921496561 (DATA4 BIGINT, DATA5 BIGINT, DATA2 BIGINT, DATA3 BIGINT)
USING parquet
OPTIONS (
  serialization.format \\'1\\'
)
PARTITIONED BY (DATA2, DATA3)
"""
regex = r'CREATE +?(TEMPORARY +)?TABLE *(?P<db>.*?\.)?(?P<table>.*?)\((?P<col>.*?)\).*?USING +([^\s]+)( +OPTIONS *\([^)]+\))?( *PARTITIONED BY \((?P<pcol>.*?)\))?'

text2 = "DATA4 BIGINT, DATA5 BIGINT, DATA2 BIGINT, DATA3 BIGINT, data9"
pattern2 = re.compile(r"(?P<pcol>((((DATA)|(data))\d)*)?)*")

text = text2 #ddl_string
pattern = re.compile(pattern2) #regex)

def part01():
    print ("\npart 01")
    lst_data = []
    if ( ((matches)) != None ):
        print(' Found!')
        
        print (matches)
        for elem in matches:
          if (elem[0] != '') : 
            print('--> {0}'.format(elem[0]))
            lst_data.append(elem[0])
    else:
        print('No match Found!\n')
    return lst_data
    
def part02():
    print ("\npart 02")
    if ( ((matches)) != None ):
        print(' Found!')
        print (matches)
        
        #print (matches.groups)
        for elem in matches:
          if (elem.group(0) != '') : 
             print(elem.group(0))

def part03():
    print ("\npart 03")
 
    if ( ((matches)) != None ):
        lst_grp = list(matches)
        print(' lst_grp[0]               : {0}'.format(lst_grp[0]))
        print(' lst_grp[0].re.groupindex : {0}'.format(lst_grp[0].re.groupindex))
        
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856238/how-to-get-group-name-of-match-regular-expression-in-python
        # groupdict - None means a group never was used in a match
        print(' lst_grp[0].groupdict()   : {0}'.format(lst_grp[0].groupdict()))
        
        for match in matches:
            print (" last : {} ".format(match.lastgroup))
    
def part04():
    print ("\npart 04")
    match = pattern.match(text)
    print(True) if match and 'pcol' in match.groupdict() else print(False)
    print("Found 'pcol'") if match and 'pcol' in match.groupdict() else print("Didn't found 'pcol'")
    print(match.group('pcol'))
    
#    names_used = [name for pcol, value in matchobj.groupdict().iteritems() if value is not None]

matches = (re.finditer(pattern, text))
returnedData01 = part01()
print (' returned --> {0}'.format(returnedData01))
# print (type(returnedData01))

matches = (re.finditer(pattern, text))
part02()

matches = (re.finditer(pattern, text))
part03()

matches = (re.finditer(pattern, text))
part04()
```